# How can I reference a video file so that it works with MediaElement after a WPF app has been published to a self-contained, single file executable?

Tags: c#, wpf, exe, clickonce, mediaelement

I have a C# .Net 5 WPF application where I'm trying to play an MP4 video as the background of a UserControl. When I set the Source property of a MediaElement to
`<MediaElement Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Media/home_background.mp4"...` and run the application in the debugger, the video plays without any issues.

However, when I publish the application as a self-contained single-file executable using ClickOnce, the video fails to play, even though it's contained within the .exe file. Upon inspecting the contents of the .exe file with an unarchiver, I was able to identify the pack which included the video file and in a separate video player it plays just fine.

Publishing without choosing "produce single-file" results in a lot of files and a functional video playback.

I've tried setting the properties of the video to different settings, especially "Content" for build action and "Always copy", but this hasn't resolved the issue. I suspect that I'm not referencing the video correctly within the application, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

**How can I properly reference the video file so that the MediaElement can still play it even after it was published?**

Comment: Why are you using `siteoforigin` instead of `application`? What's the `Build Action` of the file and how exactly do you publish the app?

Comment: Because I get a MediaFailed Event from my MediaElement which states that only URIs in the format pack://siteoforigin are supported. Initially the BuildAction was set to Content and it works fine in the debugger but as soon as I publish it stops working bc. the resource was not found. I tried every Build action with no luck.

Comment: For publishing I right click on the project -> Publish -> Publish with ClickOnce